# How to use ember-apollo-client?

Tags: python, django, ember.js, graphql, apollo-client

I am trying to use graphql through apollo-client. On frontend there is Ember, on backend we have django and graphql server, implemented on this tutorial (https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-python/0-introduction/). 
 The Ember application is on 4200 port, the graphql server is proxied on 8000/graphql  (ember s --proxy http://localhost:8000)

I tried to follow this guide (https://www.howtographql.com/ember-apollo/1-getting-started/), but without graphcool, because we have backend.

In a controller signup.js I have

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';
import Mutation from '../gql/mutation';
```

I have injected apollo this way

```
export default Controller.extend({
    apollo: Ember.inject.service(),
```

And the mutation is this

```
actions: {
    signUp() {
        let username = this.get('username');
        let password = this.get('password');
        let email = this.get('email');
        const credentials = { username, password, email };
        let mutation = Mutation.CREATE_USER;

        return this.get('apollo').mutate({mutation, credentials}, 'createUser').then(() => {
        this.set('username', '');
        this.set('email', '');
        this.set('password', '');
        console.log('user created successfully!');
    }).catch(error => console.log('ERROR!!!!111:', error));
```

After clicking submit button in a form, I got this message

```
POST http://localhost:4200/graphql 500 (Internal Server Error)
ServerParseError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

What can I do?

Comment: Are you sure that this isn't an API issue? Would be helpful if you could include the request payload. Please note that you can use `async` / `await` if using an up-to-date version of Ember. Makes the code much more readable IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so a few things to help you out:

- If you are using Chrome and go to the dev tools, go to Network -> Preview. This should display some markup with more information about the error.
- I'm not sure what your graphql mutation file looks like but you should probably be importing it just as `import mutation from ../gql/mutation`. Then call it with `this.get('apollo').mutate({mutation, credentials}, 'createUser')`
- Make sure that the relative path to your graphql file is correct
- I would recommend having your route extend `ComponentQueryManager` and then removing the injected Apollo service